# Increase Volume of Beep

Tags: c#, volume, beep

I use this code to generate a Beep:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool Beep(int frequencyHz, int durationMs);

private void DoBeep() {
    Beep(800, 500);
}
```

Now, I am searching for a way to increase the volume of the Beep. Can someone help me about that, please?

Comment: Volume? Install bigger beeper the only way. Or output beep onto sound card, where you can connect powerful speakers.

Comment: Why are you using Interop (and an old Win32 method) instead of [Console.Beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want to control the volume of individual beeps? The Beep function was written for old buzzers and won't even work in Vista and XP. In Windows 7 it redirects to the sound card, so you are really looking for ways to change the sound card's volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the BIOS beep, there is no way to adjust volume. It is really designed for testing and debugging hardware setups. You could try MessageBeep which uses the default sound device (i.e. speakers).
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And as the [Beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation says, `most developers had moved on to calling the MessageBeep function `

Answer (score 0):

The [`Beep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277(v=vs.85).aspx) function was designed for ancient (early 90s) hardware that included a separate sound chip aside from the normal sound card. This sound chip could basically only emit tones, not true sounds. Nowadays, `Beep` is simply an alias to `MessageBeep`.

To adjust the volume of `MessageBeep`, you should adjust the sound volume for your program.

Comment: There *is* a .NET function call, [Console.Beep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fe3hdb1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yes, but it's still obsolete. Quoted from the docs you linked to: "[...] before Windows 7 depends on the presence of a 8254 programmable interval timer chip. Starting with Windows 7, it depends on the default sound device.". IOW: In pre-windows 7, it simply doesn't work (unless you own an ancient PC), in Windows 7 it works because it is aliased to the new function.